# Изменить работу функции перевода из 10 в n систему счисления

Tags: c++, рекурсия

У меня есть код, который переводит из 10 С.С в любую другую, с основанием меньше 10.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void dec_to_bin(int n, int a){
  if (n >= 2)
    dec_to_bin(n / a,a);
  cout <<  n % a;
}

int main(){
  int n,a;
  cin >> n >> a;
  dec_to_bin(a,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы первая функция не выводила результат, а возвращала его в виде строки
Но не пойму, как это реализовать

Думаю примерная реализация такая

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void dec_to_bin(int n, int a, string res){
  if (n >= 2)
    dec_to_bin(n / a,a,res);
  res += string(n%a);
}

int main(){
  int n,a;
  string s = {""};
  cin >> n >> a;
  dec_to_bin(a,n,s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уже есть какие-то попытки, которые можете показать?

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Передавайте `res` по ссылке: `string &res`.
- Замените `string(n%a)` на `to_string(n%a)`, или на олд-скульный `'0' + n%a`.

Ну и `string s = {""};` можно заменить на `string s;`, разницы никакой.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался